# Is it possible to obtain a simplified expression for the product of the following matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I am trying to figure out if it is possible to simplify the matrix expression for $M$ in terms of $x_i,y_i$:

$ M(x_i,y_i)=(A+\left[B_0+\sum_{i=1}^{m}B_i x_i\right])^{-1}(A-\left[B_0+\sum_{i=1}^{m}B_i y_i\right])$

Where $x_i,y_i \in \mathbb{R} $ are scalars, $ A=A^T \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} $ is a symmetric matrix and $B_i \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$

A constraint of the form:

$ \boldsymbol v = M(x_i,y_i) \boldsymbol v_0 $

is a convex constraint?

Where $\boldsymbol v_0 \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is a given vector while $\boldsymbol v \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$

Comment: Probably not without any more information. Do we know anything else? For instance, is it known that $A$ is positive definite?

Comment: Yes $A$ is positive definite while there is no general structure on $B_i$

Comment: If the $B_i$ were low-rank, we might be able to do something with the Woodbury identity, but I don't think there's much to be done to this expression as is.

Answer (score 1):

One way to rewrite the expression is as follows. Let $A^{1/2}$ denote the symmetric positive definite square root of $A$, and let $A^{-1/2}$ denote the inverse of $A^{1/2}$. 
Let $C_i = A^{-1/2}B_i A^{-1/2}$.
We can write 
$$
M(x_i,y_i) = A^{-1/2}\left(I + C_0 + \left[\sum_{i=1}^{m}C_i x_i\right]\right)^{-1}\left(I-\left[C_0+\sum_{i=1}^{m}C_i y_i\right]\right)A^{1/2}.
$$